# Remove the minimize/maximize buttons on views

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I would like to hide the minimize/maximize buttons for views in Eclipse RCP.

Currently I'm running an RCP 3 product in RCP 4 (Compatability mode).

This is the top bar of the view containing all of the buttons. (I've covered up the logos etc)

[image: Before]

One method of removing the buttons is to create a `style.css` file and to specify that the buttons shouldn't be visible.

```
.MPartStack 
{
    swt-maximize-visible: false;
    swt-minimize-visible: false;
}
```

This results in this.

[image]

This is successfully removing the minimize/maximise buttons but is also shifting down the drop down button to a row below.

What might be causing this?

**Update**
As an alternative I've tried removing `addons.swt` from the `e4xmi` file. This included `CleanupAddon`, `DnDAddon` and `MinMaxAddon`. The buttons still remained.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. The second row is used if the tab renderer thinks there isn't enough space for everything in one row. Possibly using the curved tab is causing this.

Comment: I didn't notice that! Why might one be using a curved one and the other not? They are both the same just with and without the css.

Comment: `swt-simple: false;` in the CSS gives the curved style, several of the standard styles specify this.

Comment: This was my mistake. I had `swt-simple` set to false in the second example. I've updated it with the css only containing what I mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this by changing the perspectives and views to the `e4xmi` file instead of the `plugin.xml` and setting them to not be toolbars.

In the `plugin.xml` file you can't specify if the `view` is a toolbar. In the `e4xmi` you can specify whether the `part` is a toolbar or not.

Here is the part configuration.

[image]